# How to generate UML Diagrams in Visual Studio Professional 2013? C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, uml, diagrams

So I was trying to figure out if there's a way to generate UML Diagrams (Class Diagrams and Sequence Diagrams) in Visual Studio Professional 2013. I've found that if I right click on my project select view and then view Class Diagram, a class diagram will appear, however this class diagram won't show relationships between classes such as composition or aggregation.

[Visual Studio Print](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/669x499q90/r/661/v3BsW9.png)

For example, the variable 'numeroProdutos' on class 'Fresco' is of the 'Produto' type, however the diagram does not show the composition relationship between both those classes. Is there any way to make a proper UML diagram in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: I recommend using Doxygen.  The latest version has a UML look-a-like drawing.  I'm using Doxygen to generate HTML class diagrams.

Comment: Is doxygen a plugin for visual studio or a standalone program?

Comment: To my knowledge, it is a standalone program.  Go to their website and see if anybody has made any VS plugins.